# Check if Android app is requesting location updates

Tags: android, location

Is it possible to ask the location manager if is has any listeners?

/Per

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, sorry. The `LocationManager` API assumes that you are keeping track of your own listeners.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so with the public API.  When you use `addGpsStatusListener` or `addNmeaListener` on `LocationManager`, it adds them to private variables.  If you really wanted them, say for testing purposes, you could use reflection.